# Is it possible to select stylesheet.cssRule[] with a class name or ID?

Tags: javascript, css

Currently, I can use

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.fontSize = "16";
```

CSS:

```
h1 {font-sze: 12}
.someClass {}
```

to select the first style sheet, the first rule and change the font size to 16. But as the CSS file get huge, it's impossible to track which index number of the rules in which, is there a workaround to select the rules by class name or ID, etc?

Comment: I don't think so, but you still can add inline styles with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such method available. Specifically, the API only allows for deleting and inserting rules. On top of that, browsers may deny access to even that based on where the stylesheet originates.

Read more about it here:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet